# How to fix duplicate key value violates unique constraint error in Postges 9+

Tags: sql, windows, postgresql, duplicates, psqlodbc

Sometimes strange duplicate key error

```
duplicate key value violates unique constraint "session_pkey"
Key (workplace)=(WIN-N9BSKUNKBC8 ) already exists.
```

Occurs in script:

```
delete from session where workplace='WIN-N9BSKUNKBC8' ;
INSERT INTO session (workplace,ipaddress,logintime,loggeduser)
SELECT 'WIN-N9BSKUNKBC8' , inet_client_addr()::CHAR(14),current_timestamp::CHAR(28),CURRENT_USER WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM session WHERE workplace='WIN-N9BSKUNKBC8' )
```

Sript is running form windows task scheduler on every 10 minutes. Error occurs only sometimes.

How to fix this ?
Table is defined as

```
CREATE TABLE public.session
(
    loggeduser character(10) ,
    workplace character(16) NOT NULL,
    ipaddress character(20) ,
    logintime character(28) ,
    activity timestamp with time zone,
    CONSTRAINT session_pkey PRIMARY KEY (workplace)
)
```

Environment:

```
PostgreSQL 13.1, compiled by Visual C++ build 1914, 64-bit
Windows server 2019
psqlODBC driver 13.00.0000
```

Comment: Could it be that the select is returning more than one row?

Comment: no. As you see, select checks for primary key value which cannot be duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `on conflict`:

```
INSERT INTO session (workplace,ipaddress,logintime,loggeduser)
    SELECT 'WIN-N9BSKUNKBC8',     
          inet_client_addr()::CHAR(14),current_timestamp::CHAR(28),
CURRENT_USER 
    ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
```

Given that you have only one row going in, my guess is that the problem is due to concurrency issues.

Comment: This code leaves old data in table. New time, ip address and user should inserted. Old values should replaced. Also code should run in Postgres 9 versions also.

Comment: @Andrus . . . Your question is:  "How to fix this ? "  This answers the question you have asked in this question for all supported versions of Postgres.  If you have a different question, ask a *new* question with a clear explanation (sample data and desired results help).  If you are using an unsupported version of Postgres, please explain why.

Comment: @Andrus add to your question exactly which PostgreSQL version your query needs to run. Upserts were introduced in 9.5 (which is btw already EOL): https://endoflife.software/applications/databases/postgresql

Comment: Code in question causes exception is supported Postgres 13.1 It deletes possible existing key before adding and must work as it is. I need to use it starting from postgres 9.0 since some customers are using this version and dont want to upgrade.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Your answer produces wrong result. In case of conflict your code does not update data in table and leaves old wrong content in table. 
Changed question title to `How to fix duplicate key value violates unique constraint error in Postges 9+`. Customers are using different Postgres versions starting at 9.0 and dont want to upgrade.